# Can not bind parameter to CDbCommand

Tags: sql, database, pdo, yii, dbcommand

say, i am going to follow the good practice of avoiding sql injection. so this is not good:

```
      $query="SELECT id,tag  FROM tbl_tags WHERE tag LIKE '%".$tag."%' ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 0,10 ";
```

in stead i have to use parameter binding:

```
     $query="SELECT id,tag  FROM tbl_tags WHERE tag LIKE :tag ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 0,10 ";
     $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
 $command->bindParam(":tag", "%{$tag}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $models = $command->queryAll();
```

But this generates: Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

How can i bind this LIKE oriented parameter ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use query builder. So your query will look like following:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id, tag')
    ->from('tbl_tags')
    ->where('tag like :tag', array(':tag' => "%{$tag}%"))
    ->order('creation_time desc')
    ->limit('0, 10')
    ->queryAll()
```

It's better if you're looking for a good practice.

P.S.: Replied from iPhone, excuse typos.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the manual page for this function or by googling for the error message.

Both will tell you that bindValue() have to be used instead.

Comment: yii is poorly documented. i still don't know what the difference between bindParam() and bindValue(). However the problem is solved, by altering the parameter a little bit: $tag='%$tag%'; then i can use bindParam().

Comment: It's not yii, it's PDO, which is perfectly documented in PHP manual